# Installed Momentics IDE on linux but can't use qcc in terminal

Tags: blackberry-10, qcc

I have installed "Momentics IDE 2.1.2
for linux_64bit" on my lubuntu 20.04 machine and I have also installed the SDK. But when I try to run the command qcc from the momentics folder it always say that qcc not found. I have tried to add the momemtics directory to the PATH but still it doesn't work.
Can anyone please help me out?

By the way I'm trying to build retroarch BlackBerry 10 cores.

Edit:

Got qcc to work. There was a env.sh file in the momentics folder.
I just used `$source env.sh`
and it's working fine.